# Where to get a MongoDB Qt Driver

Tags: qt, mongodb

I am currently looking for a way to connect to MongoDB in Qt.So far i have not come across driver i could use to connect to MongoDB although there is a c++ library on the MongoDB website.Has anyone been able to use Qt with MongoDB.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the C++ library? You should be able to use it in a QT application without major issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ driver is the driver to use.